# Biztalk orchestration query

Tags: biztalk

Can we bind the two different WCF-BasicHttp Send Ports pointing different Web Service in the same Orchestration??

Comment: do you mean WCF-BasicHttp sendports?  What issues are you having?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to invoke more than 1 type of web service in the same orchestration

Comment: Why do you think you cannot? It seems like it should be straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have two different services on contract level (different operations/message types), you'll have to specify two logical ports in your orchestration.
If you want to call the same web service (on contract level), you have three options.  In order of my personal preference:
- Direct binding the logical port
- Role links (using Role Links) and define the party, based on your internal logic
- Create two different ports of the same port type and send your message to the right port, based on your logic

cheers